# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate control + alt + L and Android XML layouts order

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, if I press control + alt + L, the attributes of all views are reorderer correctly, and the layouts doesn't change of position

The problem is with IntelliJ Idea Ultimate the layouts are reordered, not only the attributes. I tried to set the XML style to the Android style in the set from menu inside Editor > XML.

Anyone is having this issue?

Comment: What's your keyboard layout?

Comment: English international. With Android studio I haven't this problem. I tried even to import the xml style from Android studio to intellij and the problem is still there...